# Are My Flags Marked Useful or Helpful Here?

Tags: feature-request, flags, profile-page, tooltips

I was scanning the new Profile page to see of I could catch any bugs but this one has been bothering me for rather long time. Looking at the tooltip when the cursor is hovering over the helpful flags, it says that...

[image]

...

> Total number of raised flags **marked useful**

Yet the flags are supposedly marked ***helpful***. So to stop the confusion, can we change the original tooltip to this tooltip?:

> Total number of raised flag marked helpful

Edit: This is ***not*** a duplicate to Oded's question on the new bugs and feedback question for the profile page. This is just one ***feature-request*** I want implemented, not a bug.

Comment: Thanks @animuson! Kinda weird I forgot to change the text...

Comment: Why roll back the change? You've not been consistent in your capitalization for [your other questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A278543+is%3Aquestion)...

Comment: While both can be used interchangeably in the correct scenarios, "Total number of flags marked "*useful*" reads better than "Total number of flags marked *helpful*".  Also "Useful flags" reads better than "Helpful flags". But that's just me, and I didn't care about full stops in banners where most others seemed to... Either way they should be the same

Comment: How exactly @Al E?

Comment: That's the "master list" of bugs and issues for the new profile page.

Comment: Yes, but this isn't. It could be used as *an answer* but not as the same question.